# How to create a TypeScript interface definition for an overloaded function with string-indexed array?

Tags: typescript, knockout-validation

I am working on a TypeScript definition file for the [knockout validation plugin](https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation). One of the things I'm stuck on has to do with how new validation rules are defined in that library.

The way to create a basic synchronous validator for `ko.validation` is like so:

```
ko.validation.rules['myrulename'] = {
    message: 'default message to display when validation fails',
    validator: function (value, params) {
        // use value and params to evaluate rule, 
        // then return true if valid, false if invalid
    }
}
```

This would be straightforward, however there is a slightly different way to create an asynchronous validator:

```
ko.validation.rules['myrulename'] = {
    async: true,
    message: 'default message to display when validation fails',
    validator: function (value, params, callback) {
        // use value and params to evaluate rule, 
        // then invoke callback to indicate pass / fail
        // this function does not return a bool (it is void)
    }
}
```

The asynchronous callback can take either a bool (for validation pass/fail) or an object literal (`isValid` for pass/fail, and `message` to change the validation message). For this, I have created the following:

```
interface KnockoutValidationAsyncCallbackArgs {
    isValid: bool;
    message: string;
}

interface KnockoutValidationAsyncCallback {
    (result: bool): void;
    (result: KnockoutValidationAsyncCallbackArgs): void;
}
```

Here is a trimmed down version of my `KnockoutValidationStatic` which exposes the rules array. I have also create a special interface for the rules array to specify string indexing:

```
interface KnockoutValidationRulesArray extends Array {
    [index: string]: KnockoutValidationRule;
}

interface KnockoutValidationStatic {
    rules: KnockoutValidationRulesArray;
    ... other members defined on this interface
}

interface KnockoutStatic {
    validation: KnockoutValidationStatic;
}
```

What I am stuck on is the `KnockoutValidationRule`. I have tried the following:

```
interface KnockoutValidationRule {
    async?: bool;
    message: string;
    validator(value: any, params: any): bool;
    validator(value: any, params: any, callback: KnockoutValidationAsyncCallback): void;
}
```

This works fine for synchronous validator declarations. However when I create an asynchronous one, I get the following error(s):

> Cannot convert '{ message: string; validator: (value: any,params:
>   any,callback: KnockoutValidationAsyncCallback) => void }' to
>   'KnockoutValidationRule': Types of property 'validator' of types '{
>   message: string; validator: (value: any,params: any,callback:
>   KnockoutValidationAsyncCallback) => void; }' and
>   'KnockoutValidationRule' are incompatible:
>
> Call signatures of type '(value: any,params: any,callback:
>   KnockoutValidationAsyncCallback) => void' and '{ (value: any,params:
>   any): bool; (value: any, params: any,callback:
>   KnockoutValidationAsyncCallback): void; } are incompatible:
>
> Call signature expects 2 or fewer parameters

I have also considered making the callback an optional parameter, but that doesn't work because the function returns different values depending on the signature (bool without 3rd arg, void if 3rd arg is present).

**What am I doing wrong here? Is there something wrong with my string-indexed array for the rules? Is it possible to create a TypeScript interface based on how this library works?**

**Update 1**

It looks like I was on the right track with the overloads in my `KnockoutValidationRule` interface. I just discovered that if I change `ko.validation.rules` from a `KnockoutValidationRulesArray` to a `KnockoutValidationRule[]`, my test code compiles fine for both sync and async validators...

```
interface KnockoutValidationStatic {
    //rules: KnockoutValidationRulesArray; // this breaks it
    rules: KnockoutValidationRule[] // this fixes it
    ... other members defined on this interface
}
```

**Am I declaring the array wrong?**

**Update 2**

Here is some example code I am using to test the definitions:

```
/// <reference path="../../ko/knockout-2.2.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../ko/knockout.validation.d.ts" />

module TestKoVal {

    ko.validation.rules['test1'] = {
        message: '',
        validator: (value: any, params: any): bool => {
            return false;
        }
    }

    ko.validation.rules['test2'] = {
        async: true,
        message: '',
        validator: function (value: any, params: any, callback: KnockoutValidationAsyncCallback): void => {
            callback(false);
            callback(true);
            callback({ isValid: false, message: 'custom' });
        }
    }
}
```

Like I said, the above compiles fine when `ko.validation.rules` is a `KnockoutValidationRule[]`. It fails when I change it to a `KnockoutValidationRulesArray`.

Comment: I'm not an expert on this, but try splitting the KnockoutValidationAsyncCallback in two (one for each signature) and create an extra overload on the KnockoutValidationRule. Because you have two methods on the interface, I think TypeScript expects an object with two methods rather than a single matching function.

Comment: @MortenMertner thanks for the suggestion. The problem with splitting the `KnockoutValidationAsyncCallback` is that it would prevent code from being able to execute both overloads of the callback. Within a validation function, I might want to invoke either `callback(true)` or `callback({isValid: false, message: 'custom message'})`.

Comment: Could you perhaps post the classes going along with this? I could fiddle a bit with it and see if I can come up with something.

Comment: PS: Remember to send your .d.ts file for this to the guy maintaining this repo: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped

Comment: @MortenMertner, yes, I was actually going to send another pull request to boris after I have this definition file a little more fleshed out. https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/pull/134

Comment: I have posted sample test code that I am using to test compilation when making changes to the definition file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have figured out why the above won't work. In javascript, when you use the [] array syntax with a string as the indexer, you are not creating an array in the usual sense. Instead, that syntax simply adds properties to the object. The following are functionally equivalent:

```
ko.validation['test1'] = { ... };
ko.validation.test1 = { ... };
```

Comment: You are correct - this is how JavaScript works - including named elements in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You can work around the problem by modifying the KnockoutValidationRule:

```
export interface KnockoutValidationRule {
    async?: bool;
    message: string;
    validator: (value: any, params: any, callback?: KnockoutValidationAsyncCallback): bool;
}
```

And make the corresponding change where this is used:

```
ko.validation.rules['test2'] = {
    async: true,
    message: '',
    validator: (value: any, params: any, callback?: KnockoutValidationAsyncCallback): bool => {
        callback(false);
        callback(true);
        callback({ isValid: false, message: 'custom' });
    }
}
```

This unifies the two method signatures. The validation method doesn't actually need to return a bool, so the fact that the method is declared to return a bool is mainly a cosmetic/aesthetic problem.

It may be worthwhile to open a discussion around this on the [codeplex site](http://typescript.codeplex.com), as I doubt this represents uncommon use in JavaScript libraries.

Comment: A cosmetic problem? Really? So the code you have above really compiles even though it declares a bool return type, but does not return anything?

Comment: I agree that it's not pretty, can be misleading to people reading the definition, and only works in cases where you really can unify the signatures. But it does compile :)

Comment: FYI, I abandoned my attempt to string-index the rules definition as an array, and used a very close match to my code in the question. I submitted the definition file to Boris Yankov's Definitely Typed project, and is has been pulled into the master: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/knockout.validation/knockout.validation.d.ts

Comment: Thanks! I expect I'll be enjoying the fruits of your labor soon :-)